# Как сделать запрос на /products.json в Ruby on Rails?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, post, form

Есть `resources :products`. Форма выглядит так:

```
<%= form_for(product) do |f| %>
  <% if product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 6 %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image_url %>
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в хэлпер `form_for(product)` передать дополнительный параметр `url`, в котором сформировать путь c json. В самом простом случае можно просто руками забить строку

```
<%= form_for(product, url: '/products.json') do |f| %>
```

Однако, так обычно не делают, а формируют путь при помощи хэлперов, чтобы в случае изменения в routes.rb не приходилось править пути еще где-то в коде проекта

```
<%= form_for(product, url: products_path(format: :json)) do |f| %>
```